# Can't install vmfs-tools

Tags: linux, centos7

I want to install vmfs-tools to read vmdk in linux.

OS is CentOs7.

I refer here
https://centos.pkgs.org/7/forensics-x86_64/vmfs-tools-0.2.5-2.el7.x86_64.rpm.html

I could install vmfs-tools-0.2.5-2.el7.x86_64.rpm in my CentOs.

But fail this command which for installing vmfs-tools.

"sudo yum --enablerepo=forensics install vmfs-tools"

This is fail message.

[image]

[image]

Please teach me if you know about this, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Moved permanently

... Means the URL in the file.repo changed. See https://forensics.cert.org/

New direct URL to "cert" https://forensics.cert.org/centos/cert/7/x86_64/

```
# CentOS-CERT.repo
[cert]
name=CentOS-CERT
baseurl=https://forensics.cert.org/centos/cert/7/x86_64/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

Add cert.repo to `/etc/yum.repos.d/` . Then you can do `# yum install vmfs-tools`

P.S.: The site "pkgs.org" will often show outdated information.

Comment: You saved me..Thank you so much.